# Ipython from progressbar import ProgressBar Error

Tags: python, import, stanford-nlp, fractions

I want to do something according to [this github code](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python).

```
from progressbar import Progressbar, Fraction
ImportError: cannot import name 'Fraction'
```

I use ipython 2 or 3

Comment: Do you have the right `progressbar` module, and did you make sure not to name any of your own files `progressbar.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Github repo you linked to contains a file `progressbar.py`, which is an ancient (2006-era) version of [`progressbar`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar). `progressbar.py` contains a `Fraction` class, while the `progressbar` module does not. So, you'll need to change your code to point to the `progressbar.py` file from the Standford NLP Github repo.